# Lua table continues to be empty, even though I am giving it stuff

Tags: lua, lua-table

In my Lua-powered game, I am trying to create an Explorer to see all the instances that have been created. I've created a function inside my DataModel "class" (as I like to call it) that will scan the children of an item, and put it neatly inside a table.

```
function DataModel.ObjectToTable(obj)
    children = {}

    for i,v in pairs(obj:GetChildren()) do
        table.insert(children, DataModel.ObjectToTable(v))
    end

    print(obj.Name)

    dmyself = {}
    dmyself.Name = obj.Name
    dmyself.Object = obj
    dmyself.Children = children

    print(#dmyself)

    return dmyself
end
```

The issue is that, the **print(#dmyself)** is coming out as **0**. But as you can see, I just set 3 things inside of it. What could cause such a thing to happen? Am I doing something obviously wrong?

The **print(obj.Name)** line is returning what it should. I am simply stuck on 'dmyself'.

Comment: Use local variables: `children` and `dmyself` are global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` is the length of the *array part* of the Lua table; it only takes integer keys into account. More specifically,

> The length of a table t is defined to be any integer index n such that t[n] is not nil and t[n+1] is nil; moreover, if t[1] is nil, n can be zero. For a regular array, with non-nil values from 1 to a given n, its length is exactly that n, the index of its last value.

If you use `pairs`, you can see that your table is not empty. But since there's nothing in the array part of the table, it's length is zero.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for that information -- using pairs did indeed return proper results.